# Altair not rendering mark_geoshape

Tags: geopandas, altair

I have a geodataframe of 3 isochrone polygons that I am trying to visualize in Altair. The data loads fine in QGIS and Matplotlib but doesn't seem to render properly in Altair. For reference, the CRS is set to 4326.

```
gdf = gpd.read_file('https://brown-institute-assets.s3.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/Objects/pointsunknown/2021_Summer/Data/output-test.geojson')

gdf = gdf.to_crs('EPSG:4326')

alt.Chart(gdf).mark_geoshape()
```

In Altair, the result is this:

[altair error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7iVGC.png)

Comment: Solved! The polygons were too detailed.

`gdf = gdf.simplify(0.01, preserve_topology=False)`

This solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Solved in the comments:

> The polygons were too detailed. `gdf = gdf.simplify(0.01, preserve_topology=False)`